# Android Firebase addListenerForSingleValueEvent is not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know this has been asked a lot but I still can get it to work. Here's my code:

```
private int test;

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userRef = rootRef.child("Users");

test = 0;
userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(userID))
            test = 1;
        else
            test = 2;
   }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});

Log.d(TAG, "Test = " + test);
```

Here's what on Firebase:

- appname-e545e

  - Users

    - userID

I don't know why but the variable "test" always return value 0, which means  addListenerForSingleValueEvent didn't work. Thanks for helping in advanced

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using addListenerForSingleValueEvent? Shouldn't you rather want to use addChildEventListener when monitoring children nodes?

Comment: I haven't thought about using it since a lot of thread on Stack Overflow used addListenerForSingleValueEvent. I will try to see if it works or not

Comment: Hi @leScepter, I was facing an issue regarding addValueEventListener() callback, in my case onDataChange() is not yet triggering at all, not getting any error of warning form firebase.

Comment: help me out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53396190/unable-to-connect-to-firebase-db-from-my-android-app?noredirect=1#comment93694127_53396190   facing same issue with firebase db connection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. By the time your log `test`, the `onDataChange` hasn't run yet.

To see this in action, add some more logging **inside** `onDataChange`:

private int test;

```
test = 0;
userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(userID)) {
            test = 1;
        }
        else {
            test = 2;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Test2 = " + test);
   }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // Don't ignore errors
    }
});

Log.d(TAG, "Test = " + test);
```

Now you'll first see:

> Test = 0

And then once the data has loaded and `onDataChange` gets called:

> Test = 1

or

> Test = 2

For this reason you should always put (or call) the code that needs the data from the database from within `onDataChange()`.

Comment: Indeed I love your long answers <3

Comment: Am I missing something here? This code doesn't compile, you can't reference non-final local variables within an anonymous inner class.

Answer (score 1):

Good lord, I spent a few minutes here. I turned out I created the database in the firebase console AFTER downloading the google-services.json.

You have to download again google-services.json from the project config and this time will have the right reference to the database

Then clean project, uninstall and install the app to make sure the new config file is shipped.

"project_info": {
"project_number": "596410010449",
"firebase_url": "https://yourname.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",

Comment: That was my case, tnx