# Android Firebase Realtime DB : addListenerForSingleValueEvent not getting triggered

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a native android app and I have an otherwise working code to authenticate my user using firebase email/password authentication. Upon authentication, I store the details of the user in the firebase relatime database.

The only problem with it is the part when I try to query the database to check if the user already exists. Below is the code snippet which performs this query, however, the flow does not seem to enter the 'addListenerForSingleValueEvent' part:

```
private void firstTimeUser(final String chkMail){

    myRef.child("profile").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            userExists = dataSnapshot.hasChild(chkMail);
            Log.d(TAG, "UserCheck1= " + userExists);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An unexpected error occurred!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    Log.d(TAG, "UserCheck2 = " + userExists);

}
```

Some investigation I have carried out:

1. The debugging reveals that the code does not go inside onDataChange or onCancelled.
2. The variable chkMail is not null (again revealed in the debugging).
3. The app is connecting to the correct firebase DB and the the child 'profile' exists.
4. If I remove this check (whether the user exists in the DB or not), the next part of updating the firebase DB with the user details goes through fine and the data is visible on firebase dashboard. However, this should happen only if the user doesn't already exist.

I have also looked at thread [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46387359/android-firebase-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent-is-not-working?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa#). 
Incorporated the Log statements inside onDataChange (as seen in the snippet above), however UserCheck1 is not logged anywhere, suggesting execution is being skipped!

Any pointers from all you good people out there?

Comment: Try to use: `throw databaseError.toException();` in your `onCancelled` method. What does it return?

Comment: Can you add your datastructure?

Comment: Can you log databaseError in your onCancelled()? I believe it might be because of the database rules. If your user is not yet authenticated and you try to access the db values then it will give you an error.

Comment: @Alex Mamo : Added the line to the onCancelled method and the result is the same. The exception returned relates to 'userExists' value being null.

Comment: @mark922 : Tried adding a log to the onCancelled method after your comment but the result is still same. The user is authenticated fine and I have a check for that. Confirmed again in the fresh run just now.

Comment: @Andre: Below is the Firebase DB structure

Comment: {
  "baseUrl" : {
    "prediction" : "AAAAAAAAAA",
    "realTime" : "BBBBBBBB"
  },
  "profile" : {
    "a@a,com" : {
      "-LEKkDoDRUhkJ4SrEeFJ" : {
        "email" : "a@a.com",
        "foodPref" : "NonVeg",
        "name" : "XXXX",
        "vehicle" : "YYYY"
      },
      "-LEKlAXwa6ISg6Mxvaep" : {
        "email" : "a@a.com",
        "foodPref" : "NonVeg",
        "name" : "XXXX",
        "vehicle" : "YYYY"
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: Can you confirm that UserCheck2 is getting printed? Once I forgot to call a function and I was thinking that listener is not working.

Comment: UserCheck2 is getting printed indeed. Everytime!