# Android studio does not check query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent() and returns nothing

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know this question has been asked many time but still it cannot helped to solve my case.

I want to get one of the **Drivers** data from the following test:

[image]

by using the following code...

```
@Override
protected void onCreateonCreate(){
    rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    getDriverStatus();
}
public void getDriverStatus(){
    Log.d("Firebase","get driver status called...");   //works fine

    query = rootRef.child("Drivers").orderByChild("email");
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                Log.d("Firebase","Searching driver...");      // not working
                String phone = ds.child("mobile").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("Firebase",phone);

                if(phone.equalsIgnoreCase(getPhone())){
                    Log.d("Firebase","Driver found");
                    break;
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

While debugging I noted that Android studio jumps over this statement..

**query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {...}** and does not check it at all. The Logs also giv no error. Can any body tell me what is wrong in the code!!!

Comment: are you getting data in snapshot.

Comment: What does this line of code return `Log.d("Firebase",phone);`? Please responde with @.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Firebase addListenerForSingleValueEvent is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46387359/android-firebase-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent-is-not-working)

Comment: Atif AbbAsi yes

Comment: @Alex Mamo nothing. From   "    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {    "  -- upto --    "   });   "   everything is skipped by compiler

Comment: @MuzzammilHussain Have you tried to move all the code from inside `onCreateonCreate()` and  `getDriverStatus()` methods right into your `onCreate()` method? Does it work that way?

Comment: I tried it but the result is same... @Alex Mamo

Comment: @MuzzammilHussain I see in your code that this line `Log.d("Firebase","Searching driver...");` works, is that correct?

Comment: @AlexMamo inside my logs I'm seeing only this: "get driver status called..." . Nothing inside onDataChanged() works...!

Comment: What does this line of code print `Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());`?

Comment: @AlexMamo this is also skipped...

Comment: @MuzzammilHussain Can you somehow show us the entire code for your activity class?

Comment: @MuzzammilHussain It is normal that the debugger steps over the `ValueEventListener` that you pass in. The data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously, and the code in `ValueEventListener` will only be called once there is a response from the server. See [my answer that Ellisan linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46387359/android-firebase-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent-is-not-working) for an explanation of this. If you put a breakpoint on the `for` loop inside `onDataChange`, does it get called?

Comment: In addition, please don't ignore errors. Implement `onCancelled` like this `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }` to get a clear signal if there is a problem.

Comment: thanks to everyone ,, specially to you @AlexMamo for your kindness. The problem was just due to the attribute "query" was not public ... lol !

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it by making the attribute "query" **public**

Simply changed

```
Query query;
```

to

```
public Query query;
```

and it worked...!

Thanks for everyone helped me solving the issue.