# Unable to connect to firebase DB from my android app

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am unable to connect to my firebase DB.

My code:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("error");
mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                try {
                    //getting value as dataSnapshot;
                } catch (Exception ignored) { }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                databaseError.getCode();
            }
        });
```

`OnDataChange()` and `onCancelled()` are not getting triggered and "error" is my collection name in firebase DB console.

My firebase dependencies in app build file:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
```

Comment: what are you getting in the logcat?

Comment: make sure Internet permission is added in manifest file and this link may help you https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference&method=addListenerForSingleValueEvent

Comment: Hi @ZahoorSaleem, i have already included the internet permission.

Comment: @PeterHaddad, I was not getting any errors or warnings(checked in both normal logcat and firebase logcat).

Comment: show logs please

Comment: Did you add the right google-services.json to your project, the right SHA digest in your firebase console and the right ACL rules in your DB?

Comment: Hi @shadowsheep, I was using the correct google-services.json file and right SHA digest in firebase console, and ACL rules are true for read and write. remaining firebase services(like config, analytics, invites) are working fine, but I am unable to connect to the firebase DB, please help me regarding this.

Comment: Hi @HarKal i was not getting any error or warning logs regarding this, i have checked with normal logs and firebase filtered logs, if i get any logs regarding it then it will be more helpful for me to debug the issue, not able to understand what is going wrong their, please help me regarding this.

Comment: If you try to log the content of your `dataSnapshot` object, what do you get in the logcat?

Comment: Hi @AlexMamo, the trigger was not going inside of dataSnapshot object(i.e onDataChange()), while debugging the trigger was going upto addListenerForSingleValueEvent() and closing totally, the callback is not triggering. let me know any further details needed. please help me regarding this.